# How to organize my data for the development of a georeferenced model of house prices?

Tags: rstudio, geospatial, spatial, arcgis, economics

I have many databases with several features of houses such as: type(residential,industrial), location, the number of floors, price per square meter, area of the property. Those are all my variables.Also I have unique code number(one code per house). I have 17 databases. From 2000 to 2017. One excel file per year. In each excel file  there are 50 sheets(one sheet per state) with the locations of the houses with their several features(those that I mentioned before). All the data bases have different numbers of observations(number of houses) per state. They kept the observations of the previous year and add some more next year. For example, In the database of the year 2000, in one state(one excel sheet) I have 100 observations. But the next year there are 40 observations more.

This is a sheet( you can run this in Rstudio):

```
 structure(list(Code = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102), Denom = c("A.H.", 
"Jr.", "Jr.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Av.", "Calle", "Malecón", "Malecón", 
"Malecón", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Jr.", "Calle", "Jr.", "Jr.", 
"Ovalo", "Malecón", "Malec.", "Malecón", "Malecón", "Malecón", 
"Malec.", "Av.", "Pque.", "Pque.", "Pque.", "Pque.", "Pque.", 
"Pque.", "Av.", "Av.", "Av.", "Urb.", "Cerro", "Malecón", "Urb.", 
"Malec.", "Malec.", "Urb.", "Jr.", "Urb.", "Av.", "Av.", "Av.", 
"Av.", "Urb.", "Av,", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", 
"Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", 
"Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", 
"Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Av.", "Urb.", "A.H.", "Av.", "Av.", 
"Av.", "Malecón", "Malecón", "Malecón", "Av.", "Malecón", "A.H.", 
"Urb.", "Malecón", "Malecón", "Malecón", "Malec.", "Malecón", 
"Baln.", "Baln.", "Baln.", "Baln.", "Baln.", "Urb.", "Baln.", 
"Baln.", "Urb.", "Urb.", "Urb."), Location = c("21 de Marzo", 
"Abtao Cdra. 6 / 2 de Mayo", "Abtao Frente Bungalows FAP", "Asoc. Villas de Ancón", 
"Asoc. Villas de Ancón", "Autovía Malecón Las Colinas", "Bajada Los Cangrejos Playa Hermosa", 
"Bardelli Cdra. 3", "Bardelli Cdra. 4", "Bardelli Cdra. 4", "Brisas de Santa Rosa", 
"Bungalows", "Bungalows", "Daniel A. Carrión Cdra. 4", "Daniel A. Carrión Cdra. 4", 
"Dos de Mayo Cdra. 6", "Dos de Mayo esq. Carrión", "Entrada Ancón", 
"Ferreyros Cdra. 1", "Ferreyros Cdra. 2", "Ferreyros Cdra. 3", 
"Ferreyros Cdra. 3", "Ferreyros Cdra. 5", "Ferreyros Cdra. 6", 
"Florida - Miramar", "Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", 
"Industrial", "Industrial", "Industrial", "La Florida Urb. Miramar", 
"La Florida Urb. Miramar", "La Florida Urb. Miramar", "La Pera", 
"Lancheros", "Las Colinas", "Las Colinas", "Las Colinas", "Las Colinas", 
"Las Colinas, Malec. Pardo", "Loa Cdra. 2", "Los Alamos", "Miramar", 
"Miramar", "Miramar", "Miramar", "Miramar", "Miramar", "Miramar 1ra. Fila", 
"Miramar 1ra. Fila", "Miramar 1ra. Fila", "Miramar 1ra. Fila", 
"Miramar 1ra. Fila", "Miramar 1ra. Fila", "Miramar 2da. Fila", 
"Miramar 2da. Fila", "Miramar 2da. Fila", "Miramar 2da. Fila", 
"Miramar 2da. Fila", "Miramar 2da. Fila", "Miramar 2da. Fila", 
"Miramar 3ra. Fila", "Miramar 4ta. Fila", "Miramar 4ta. Fila", 
"Miramar 4ta. Fila", "Miramar 4ta. Fila", "Miramar 4ta. Fila", 
"Miramar 4ta. Fila", "Miramar Av. La Florida", "Miramar Calle 23, 2da. Fila", 
"Miramar Calle Sorrento Cdra. 1", "Miramar Mz. 11,  Lote 2, 2da. Fila", 
"Miramar Urb. Miramar", "Nueva Era", "Oasis", "Panam. Norte Km. 38.5", 
"Panamericana Norte KM. 42.0", "Panamericana Norte.", "Pardo Urb. Bungalows", 
"Pardo Urb. Bungalows", "Pardo Urb. Colinas", "Parque Esq. Malec. Ferreyros", 
"Playa Hermosa", "San Francisco de Asis", "San José", "San Martín", 
"San Martín Cdra. 3", "San Martín Cdra. 4", "San Martín Cdra. 4", 
"San Martín Cdra. 6", "Santa Rosa", "Santa Rosa", "Santa Rosa", 
"Santa Rosa", "Santa Rosa", "Santa Rosa", "Santa Rosa (Fte. Mar)", 
"Santa Rosa Country Club", "Villa Estar", "Virgen del Rosario", 
"Virgen del Rosario"), `Area(M²)` = c(160, 2300, 300, 300, 600, 
5231, 398, 644, 600, 682, 120, 160, 220, 420, 428, 2310, 300, 
1450, 340, 450, 750, 600, 500, 330, 246, 1230, 922, 2600, 1800, 
3000, 7500, 233, 280, 300, 130, 112938, 313, 210, 315, 315, 200, 
600, 160, 280, 300, 280, 308, 258, 280, 258, 140, 279, 280, 389, 
280, 280, 280, 351, 290, 396, 300, 250, 160, 144, 280, 175, 150, 
308, 246, 300, 259, 140, 290, 500, 108, 120, 247, 50000, 25000, 
200, 220, 220, 410, 360, 160, 140, 450, 480, 400, 420, 530, 200, 
188, 187, 200, 190, 100, 400, 200, 160, 192, 192), `$ M²` = c(100, 
220, 220, 50, 110, 220, 400, 600, 600, 600, 130, 220, 220, 70, 
200, 400, 390, 140, 660, 590, 660, 660, 660, 550, 220, 50, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 220, 220, 220, 120, 50, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 
300, 60, 220, 220, 220, 220, 180, 200, 210, 200, 200, 200, 200, 
200, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 170, 130, 90, 100, 100, 100, 
90, 100, 220, 170, 70, 170, 220, 50, 100, 145, 55, 70, 200, 200, 
170, 420, 500, 70, 180, 700, 700, 700, 600, 750, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 140, 150, 100, 80, 100, 100), Type = c("RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "CV Comercial", 
"RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", 
"RDA Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", 
"RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"I2 Industrial", "I2 Industrial", "I2 Industrial", "I2 Industrial", 
"I2 Industrial", "I2 Industrial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "PU Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"CZ Comercial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "CV Comercial", 
"PU Pre-Urbano", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", 
"RDA Residencial", "RDA Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", "RDM Residencial", 
"RDM Residencial"), Floors = c(3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 15, 15, 15, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 15, 5, 15, 15, 15, 9, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 3, 
3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 5, 3, 3, 15, 15, 15, 10, 
15, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)), row.names = c(NA, -102L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So I want to develop a GIS Model Property Valuation.A model that helps those who value real estate to have an overview of the price range that a certain state may have. So the idea is to visualize a map with all those states and see a price range( i.e 500-2000 dollars per square meters) in all the map. This should be represented by different shades of one color. The dark shades would be the most expensive(states).

So the first step is to organize the data.  I want to see some trends(from 2000-2017) in the house's price of each state and some statistical information( mean, median,etc). Finally,  How should I organize my data for the development of a georeferenced model of house prices? Should I create a database with all the observations(all years) for every state?. Each excel sheet will have all the observations of each state(from 2000-2017).

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really broad question. Probably too broad to get any meaningful answers.  With the data sets you've outlined my biggest piece of advice is to get it out of excel and use a database to store the data.  Is all of this data in excel spreadsheets currently?  Excel is not a database. It does store data and has some advantages but it's not setup well to handle queries.

Comment: Thans for the advice, I  will use Rstudio to handle that.